# WinDbg: Execute an external application every time a breakpoint is hit

Tags: windbg

Is there a way to run some external application every time a breakpoint is hit in WinDbg?

I have multiple virtual machines running in different host machines and I would like to get notified when one of them has hit a breakpoint. It would be distracting to shuffle every now and then between the RDP windows just to check whether some WinDbg has now stumbled upon some breakpoint.

I know already that it is possible for WinDbg to flash the title bar or play a sound when a breakpoint is hit.

Currently I imagine I could use a script to observe the tail of the log file, and start the external application when some appropriate pattern is added to the log file. But WinDbg-based solution would be better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax for setting a breakpoint is

```
[~Thread] bp[ID] [Options] [Address [Passes]] ["CommandString"]
```

The key thing here is *CommandString*, which (according online help)

> Specifies a list of commands that are executed

Use that together with `.shell` to run an external program